# Change .properties files after compiling in GWT/GXT?

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, constants, gxt

I'm wondering if there is any way in which someone that does not use Eclipse or any compiler is able to change/edit the .properties files and repack the war so that he/she is able to change (for example) the labels in the application.

Right now whatever modifications I make in the project's war folder in the workspace does not seem to affect the app when deploying.

Hopefully someone with a bit more experience with GWT/GXT will take the time and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,They won't effect on client.Because your app.chache.js is already prepared  and then you trying to modify the `.properties file`.

Your all messages(labels)  from `properties` file going to be used while compiling time it self.Later even if you changed there until next `compile` they wont `effect`.

For dynamic lable changes use [i18n](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html) or some third party [libraries](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dmesg/).